# Splitting tuple into segments

Tags: python-3.x

If I have the following tuple...:

```
("Year-7 [{'Name': 'Barry', 'Age': 11}, {'Name': 'Larry', 'Age': 11}]", 
"Year-8 [{'Name': 'Harry', 'Age': 11}, {'Name': 'Parry', 'Age': 11}]", 
"Year-9 [{'Name': 'Sally', 'Age': 11}, {'Name': 'Garry', 'Age': 11}]")
```

How do I split this up into the following tuples?
    ("Year-7", "Year-8, "Year-9")

```
("[{'Name': 'Barry', 'Age': 11}, {'Name': 'Larry', 'Age': 11}]", "[{'Name': 'Harry', 'Age': 11}, {'Name': 'Parry', 'Age': 11}]", "[{'Name': 'Sally', 'Age': 11}, {'Name': 'Garry', 'Age': 11}]")
```

Thanks in advance,
Jack
.................

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to take a single tuple of strings that look like a list of dictionaries, and product a new tuple of strings without the `Year-x` section?

Comment: Is it intended that you have a tuple of strings representing lists/dictionaries, or are those quotes there by accident?

Comment: @DonkeyKong Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @ByteCommander No: I ripped this from a text file, hence the dictionaries and file name are wrapped in quotes. I really need to split the string, then use .replace() if possible to remove the quotes (if that actually works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t = ("Year-7 [{'Name': 'Barry', 'Age': 11}, {'Name': 'Larry', 'Age': 11}]", 
"Year-8 [{'Name': 'Harry', 'Age': 11}, {'Name': 'Parry', 'Age': 11}]", 
"Year-9 [{'Name': 'Sally', 'Age': 11}, {'Name': 'Garry', 'Age': 11}]")

tuple([k[7:] for k in list(t)])
```

Did you also want:

```
tuple([k[:6] for k in list(t)])
```